# Mouse click with JNA

Tags: java, jna

I'm trying to simulate mouse click at window with JNA.

```
public class App {

public static final int WM_LBUTTONUP = 514;
public static final int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 513;
public static final int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x203;
static int WM_CLOSE = 0x10;
final static String winTitle = "Untitled - Notepad";

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    User32Extra user32 = (User32Extra) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32Extra.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    WinDef.HWND hwnd = user32.FindWindow(null, winTitle);
    user32.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    long y = 77 + (22 << 16);//x + (y << 16)
    WinDef.LPARAM l = new WinDef.LPARAM(y);
    WinDef.WPARAM w = new WinDef.WPARAM(0);
    user32.PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, w, l);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    user32.PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, w, l);
}
}
```

It find the window and bring it to front. but mouse click doesn't work. Also sending WM_CLOSE works. 
What's wrong with mouse click?
Tested on calculator and notepad. 
Coordinates are relative to the window.

Comment: +1...  Finding the window's position and bringing it to front cannot be done in pure Java (at least not if it's a window belonging to another app), so JNA is great here but...  The mouse click can be done using a Java Robot.  Would it be an option for you to keep using your JNA to find the window and then bring it to front and *then* use a simple Java Robot to simulate the click?

Comment: Robot moves real cursor and it's really annoying. Also it require the target window isn't overlapped with something else. But with PostMessage this will work without moving my cursor and even if the window is somewhere in background.

Comment: a) *"Robot moves real cursor and it's really annoying"* [sic]  With Robot you can: save the mouse position, move the mouse, click, move back the mouse to the old location.  It's so fast users won't even see it (been there, done that ; )    b) *"it require the target window isn't overlapped with something else"* [sic]  You said you were bringing your window to front?  (in most cases once a window is in front, it's in front...  Although I agree in some cases there may still be some thing even more "in front", but this should be more than rare no!?

Comment: I know what is robot and I can imagine many different workarounds about mouse clicking and emulation other events. But robot is still unreliable workaround. Yes, in this example the window is in front and robot will work fine. But in real word application the window can be in background. Also double click can take more time and it will not be so fast. If application needs series of clicks and other actions it can take some time. I already have JNA in this project and it can send any messages to any window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a wild guess: The click events should not be delivered to the main window but to the destination button objects themselves. On the given coordinates the button lay above the main window "hiding" it when a real click happens.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I've tested it on application which doesn't based on Windows components: netbeans, firefox and it works fine. To click button in calculator it need to find button component and send message directly to it. Thanks