# JNA | User32#PostMessage WM_MOUSEMOVE

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface, jna, mouselistener

I am new to using JNA. I am trying to simulate a mouse movement within a window.
I have a few questions;

I understand can send mouse input events by PostMessage, with JNA this looks like:

[PostMessage(WinDef.HWND hWnd, int msg, WinDef.WPARAM wParam, WinDef.LPARAM lParam)](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/User32.html#PostMessage-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND-int-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.WPARAM-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LPARAM-)

Could someone break-down these parameters for me? The first is the window handle, easy enough.
According to the docs the second is the message I want to send. Okay so I believe I want this one:

[WM_NMOUSEMOVE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousemove)

WM_MOUSEMOVE is the message I want but the parameter is calling for an int - can someone explain what I'm suppose to do here?

Taking it a step further, the remaining 2/4 parameters are WinDef.WPARAM and inDef.LPARAM. Referring again to WM_MOUSEMOVE docs:
"WPARAM Indicates whether various virtual keys are down."

So can I pass this as null if no keys are to be down? Otherwise it gives me a list of these codes that can be used, the same type which has a reference to WM_MOUSE MOVE "eg; 0x0008) Can someone tell me what these types of sequences are referred as and how I use them?

Lastly, for LPARAM, "...low-order word specifies the x-coordinate.. high-order word specifies the y-coordinate of the cursor". Okay so this would seem easily enough however JNA's [Windef.LPARAM](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/) only allows for 1 parameter (long). Whereas I notice in [what seems like C] API there is a MAKELPARAM(1, 2). So how can I specify the coordinates in JNA's LPARAM?

**Could someone please provide a working snippet - using JNA to send a mouse move event to a window. Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Generally we don't ask people to write code for us here... please at least make an initial attempt and then come back for help when it doesn't work. :)  You might start with [this question about mouse clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293626/mouse-click-with-jna) which looks like it uses the same code.

Comment: Regarding the [Windef.LPARAM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) it's a pointer-sized type, meaning it's 32-bits (Double word) on Win32 and 64-bits on Win64.  The "low order word" is the rightmost 16 bits which you can obtain just by casting the value to `short`.  The "high order word" is bits 17-32, which you can obtain by right-shifting the value by 16 bits and then casting to `short`.  To put the numbers INTO an LPARAM just create a `long` variable and use bitwise OR with the low 16 bit `short` and the high 16 bit value left-shifted 16 bits.

Comment: Finally, a brief search revealed [this project which appears to simplify and abstract mouse movements](https://github.com/Col-E/Simplified-JNA), and you might find it useful.