# JNA / WinAPI. Simulate mouse click without moving the cursor doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, c++, c, winapi, jna

**EDIT**: Sorry, but I am not sure that my questions was closed correcltly. I was suggested this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293626/mouse-click-with-jna) but it doesn't answer on my question. I am able to simulate mouse click but it doesn't work correctly as I described in my question.

---

I am still learning JNA and using it in my ***Java*** application (JNA 5.6.0 and jna-platform 5.6.0) but I hope people who familiar with ***C*** languages can understand me too because JNA is using WinAPI functions. My OS is Windows 10.

What I have:

- Swing application that launches the Warcraft III game, runs the exe file of the game.
- Low level keyboard hook that intercepts keystrokes `LowLevelKeyboardProc()` and calls `click()` method, which is described below.
- Logic that should simulate mouse clicks on the ***coordinates*** of the game window (where the Inventory, Skills and Control are located), after pressing certain ***keys*** (as shown in the picture below).

[image]

The **problem** is that I cannot achieve the correct execution of a mouse click on the coordinates of the game window.

I want to say in advance that I do not violate the rules of the game's license agreement and I want to use it only for personal purposes for the old version of the game, 1.26. Also, I've seen a similar implementation in other programming languages, but I want to implement it in Java.

Below I am attaching the 3 options that I tried, with a description of the problem:

**1**. Using `User32.INSTANCE.SendMessage()`

```
public void click(KeyBindComponent keyBindComponent) {
        final int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 513;
        final int WM_LBUTTONUP = 514;
        final int MK_LBUTTON = 0x0001;
        Map<String, Integer> cords = getCords(keyBindComponent);
        if (!cords.isEmpty()) {
            int xCord = cords.get("width");
            int yCord = cords.get("height");
            LPARAM lParam = makeLParam(xCord, yCord);
            user32Library.SendMessage(warcraft3hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, new WPARAM(MK_LBUTTON), lParam);
            user32Library.SendMessage(warcraft3hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, new WPARAM(MK_LBUTTON), lParam);
            System.out.println("x = " + xCord + " y = " + yCord);
        }
    }

public static LPARAM makeLParam(int l, int h) {
        // note the high word bitmask must include L
        return new LPARAM((l & 0xffff) | (h & 0xffffL) << 16);
    }
```

It was expected that an invisible click would be made on the **test** coordinate point (on the building). But the **problem** is that the area was allocated instead. I assume that the following sequence was performed: clicking the mouse down in the ***Сurrent mouse position*** and moving the cursor to the ***Сoordinate point for click***. But I have no idea why this happened.

[image]

**2.** Using `User32.INSTANCE.PostMessage()`

```
public void click(KeyBindComponent keyBindComponent) {
        final int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 513;
        final int WM_LBUTTONUP = 514;
        Map<String, Integer> cords = getCords(keyBindComponent);
        if (!cords.isEmpty()) {
            int xCord = cords.get("width");
            int yCord = cords.get("height");
            LPARAM lParam = makeLParam(xCord, yCord);
            user32Library.PostMessage(warcraft3hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, new WPARAM(0), lParam);
            user32Library.PostMessage(warcraft3hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, new WPARAM(0), lParam);
            System.out.println("x = " + xCord + " y = " + yCord);
        }
    }

public static LPARAM makeLParam(int l, int h) {
        // note the high word bitmask must include L
        return new LPARAM((l & 0xffff) | (h & 0xffffL) << 16);
    }
```

The **same** situation happened,instead of clicking on the coordinates, the area was selected, as well as in the case of `SendMessage()`, probably I will not re-attach the picture twice.

**3.** Using `User32.INSTANCE.SendInput()`

```
public void click(KeyBindComponent keyBindComponent) {
        Map<String, Integer> cords = getCords(keyBindComponent);
        if (!cords.isEmpty()) {
            int xCord = cords.get("width");
            int yCord = cords.get("height");
            mouseMove(xCord, yCord);
            mouseClick();
            System.out.println("x = " + xCord + " y = " + yCord);
        }
    }

void mouseMove(int x, int y) {
        final int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
        final int MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;
        INPUT input = new INPUT();
        INPUT[] move = (INPUT[]) input.toArray(2);

        // Release the mouse before moving it
        move[0].type = new DWORD(INPUT.INPUT_MOUSE);
        move[0].input.setType("mi");
        move[0].input.mi.dwFlags = new DWORD(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP);
        move[0].input.mi.dwExtraInfo = new BaseTSD.ULONG_PTR(0);
        move[0].input.mi.time = new DWORD(0);
        move[0].input.mi.mouseData = new DWORD(0);

        move[1].type = new DWORD(INPUT.INPUT_MOUSE);
        move[1].input.mi.dx = new LONG(x);
        move[1].input.mi.dy = new LONG(y);
        move[1].input.mi.mouseData = new DWORD(0);
        move[1].input.mi.dwFlags = new DWORD(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP + MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE);

        user32Library.SendInput(new DWORD(2), move, move[0].size());
    }

void mouseClick() {
        final int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
        final int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
        INPUT input = new INPUT();
        INPUT[] click = (INPUT[]) input.toArray(2);

        click[0].type = new DWORD(INPUT.INPUT_MOUSE);
        click[0].input.setType("mi");
        click[0].input.mi.dwFlags = new DWORD(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN);
        click[0].input.mi.dwExtraInfo = new BaseTSD.ULONG_PTR(0);
        click[0].input.mi.time = new DWORD(0);
        click[0].input.mi.mouseData = new DWORD(0);

        click[1].type = new DWORD(INPUT.INPUT_MOUSE);
        click[1].input.setType("mi");
        click[1].input.mi.dwFlags = new DWORD(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP);
        click[1].input.mi.dwExtraInfo = new BaseTSD.ULONG_PTR(0);
        click[1].input.mi.time = new DWORD(0);
        click[1].input.mi.mouseData = new DWORD(0);

        user32Library.SendInput(new DWORD(2), click, click[0].size());
    }
```

In this case, there is no click at all on the coordinate point. Instead, when certain keys are pressed, the mouse is clicked in **Current mouse position**.

By the way, I also tried using Java **Robot**, but it didn't work for me. Unfortunately the mouse cursor moved (disappeared) by about a milliseconds from the starting position to the point where you need to click and back to the starting position.

Thank you for reading this to the end, I apologize for such a cumbersome explanation.

Can anyone tell me what and where I made a mistake in the code? Since in all 3 options, I did not achieve the expected behavior.

Comment: Is your system (or application) DPI setting set to something other than the default?

Comment: @mnistic The DPI parameter does not change in application, it is also configured by default in the system. If we are talking about a mouse, then I have a very simple old mouse, Sven RX-160, Resolution, DPI 800.

Comment: Do you have multiple monitors with different resolutions?

Comment: @DanielWiddis No, only one with 1920x1080 resolution.

Comment: @DanielWiddis It seems to me that the closest I got to the goal is in the 3rd option with the SendInput () method, it performs a click, but does not perform a move. Perhaps I have incorrectly implemented the mouseMove () method. Although in the PostMessage and SendMessage methods I also achieved the click and movement of the mouse, but for some reason the movement occurs with the button pressed. And that's why I guess the area is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 3rd case, you did not use the `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE` flag to move the mouse, so the mouse did not actually move. And also according to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-mouseinput#remarks):

> If **`MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE`** value is specified, **dx** and **dy** contain
> normalized absolute coordinates between 0 and 65,535

```
void mouseMove(int x, int y) {
    INPUT move[2] = {};
    
    DWORD fScreenWidth = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    DWORD fScreenHeight = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    move[0].type = move[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    move[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;// Release the mouse before moving it
    move[1].mi.dx = MulDiv(x, 65535, fScreenWidth);
    move[1].mi.dy = MulDiv(y, 65535, fScreenHeight);
    move[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;

    SendInput(2, move, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

Then use the `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN` and `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP` to click the current postion.

Or you can directly merge the mouse move into the click event:

```
void mouseMoveClick(int x, int y) {
    INPUT click[3] = {};

    click[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    click[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;// Release the mouse before moving it

    DWORD fScreenWidth = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    DWORD fScreenHeight = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    click[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    click[1].mi.dx = click[2].mi.dx= MulDiv(x, 65535, fScreenWidth);
    click[1].mi.dy = click[2].mi.dy= MulDiv(y, 65535, fScreenHeight);
    click[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;

    click[2].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    click[2].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;

    SendInput(3, click, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

If you want to move back to the original position after the mouse click, you can use [`GetCursorPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcursorpos) to record the current position before moving. Then use mouseMove event or simpler [`SetCursorPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursorpos) to return to the position.

```
void click(int xCord, int yCord) {
    //mouseMove(xCord, yCord);
    POINT p = {};
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    mouseMoveClick(xCord, yCord);
    SetCursorPos(p.x, p.y);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it's really helpfull. I edited 3rd option of my code according to your example and it works like a charm. Perhaps you know what could be the problem in the first or second option using SendMessage and PostMessage? It feels like area was allocated instead as I shown on the screenshot of the game.

Comment: It is not reliable to simulate keyboard input with `SendMessage/PostMessage`, especially the pressed state of the keyboard. [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513)